# Example of non-contractible acyclic finite simplical complex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry, simplicial-complex

From the article "f-vectors of acyclic complexes" (Discrete Math. 1985) by Gil Kalai, we know that the relation between f-vectors of an acyclic simplicial complex.  In other words, one can construct an acyclic simplicial complex using Kalai's formula. I tried but didn't manage to construct one.

Can anyone please give me an example of a connected non-contractible acyclic finite simplicial complex?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [The Poincare homology $3$-sphere has a finite triangulation](http://www.eg-models.de/models/Simplicial_Manifolds/2003.04.001/_preview.html). If you take the subcomplex of simplices of dimension $\leq 2$ then this will be acyclic, but it is not contractible because it has a non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: I realized that the subcomplex of simplices of dimension $\leq 2$ is the wrong thing to consider. What you really want is the subcomplex given by the surface of the docecahedron (i.e. you want to ignore *all* simplices in the interior, not just the $3$-simplices)

Comment: @William: Thank you so much. Is there any easy example? Also, can you please help me to write the graph (in the sense of Proposition 2.1 of https://www.math.ust.hk/~mabfchen/Paper/Graham-Homotopy.pdf) associated with the above acyclic simplicial complex?

Comment: I think this subcomplex of the Poincare homology sphere is actually a relatively simple example of such a thing. Since the geometric realization of a simplicial complex is in particular a CW complex, by Whitehead and Hurewicz if $|\Delta|$ is acyclic but not contractible then it must have non-trivial fundamental group. I don't know a simpler example of a finite acyclic complex with non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: The link I posted in my first comment gives a description of a triangulation of the full Poincare homology sphere using $16$ vertices, and you can restrict this to the surface of the dodecahedron to get a $2$-dimensional complex $K$. Proposition 2.1 that you linked to says that if you take the barycentric subdivision $sd(K)$ and then take the $1$-skeleton $sk(sd(K))$, then the set of subcomplexes of this $1$-skeleton is isomorphic as a simplicial complex to $sd(K)$. So, you might not be able to express $K$ as a set of subcomplexes of a graph (I'm not sure), but for $sd(K)$ you can.

Comment: This paper https://people.kth.se/~bjorner/files/poincare.pdf contains explicit small constructions, one with 10 vertices, and in general the website of Frank Lutz http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~lutz/ is a good place to start looking for such examples.